# Change nightly Rust version?

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo, rust-language-server

I tried to build [rls](https://github.com/rust-lang/rls) by the command `cargo +nightly build --release -Z unstable-options`, but got the following errors:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `expect_none` found for enum `Option<Fingerprint>` in the current scope
    --> /Users/cjw/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/rustc-ap-rustc_span-705.0.0/src/lib.rs:2003:48
     |
2003 |                 cache[index].replace(sub_hash).expect_none("Cache slot was filled");
     |                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Option<Fingerprint>`
```

After searching it, I found that `expect_none` is a nightly feature and seemingly has been removed.

So I think maybe I should change the rust compiler version to fix the compilation problem. If this is the correct solution, how could I do it? Can anyone provide some detail suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `rustup` you can manage different nightly versions. See [The Edition Guide](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/rustup-for-managing-rust-versions.html) for more.

As [`Option::expect_none`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.expect_none) was [removed on March 25th](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/83349), we can get the nightly for March 24th in the following way:

```
rustup toolchain install nightly-2021-03-24 --force
```

Note: the `--force` option was used as the components `rustfmt` and `clippy` might be missing.

Switch to the newly downloaded toolchain:

```
rustup default nightly-2021-03-24
```

The following `main.rs` should now panic, as expected:

```rust
#![feature(option_expect_none)]

fn main() {
    let value = Some(42);
    value.expect_none("The answer");
}
```

---

If you're curious, you could try this with `nightly-2021-03-26` and you'll find that it will give you the expected error, indicating it was indeed removed:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `expect_none` found for enum `Option<{integer}>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:5:11
  |
5 |     value.expect_none("Expected none!");
  |           ^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `Option<{integer}>`
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also have to change the compile instruction from `cargo +nightly build --release -Z unstable-options` to `cargo build --release -Z unstable-options` to make it works.

Comment: Aren't you think that install the `nightly` toolchain using `--force` flag` is not a good idea, please let me know that if you have tested this